# That is/was great. - which one should I use?

Tags: meaning-in-context, tense

**Question 1**

> A: I won the lottery last week.

> B: That **is/was** great.

Which one should I use?

What are the differences?

**Question 2**

> A: I climbed the highest mountain last month.

> B: That **sounds/sounded** so cool.

Which one should I use?

What are the differences?

Comment: Is the same person saying both sentences, or is the second sentence someone responding to the first speaker?

Comment: From B's standpoint, it **is** great to hear of A's good luck, and the story of A's mountain climb **sounds** cool. (B might use **sounded** if they were talking about hearing the news in the past.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that referring to the news or narration of an event is done by using verbs in the present tense. So, the appropriate response to Q.1 is, "That is great."

Likewise, for Q.2 the appropriate response is, "That sounds cool."

Here, "that" refers more to the news about what A did, rather than what A did. Obviously, the content of the news is evaluated; but, ultimately, you are commenting on what you have just learned: "It is great (to learn) that you won the lottery." "It sounds cool (to hear) that you climbed the highest mountain."

Referring directly to a past event, however, is done by using verbs in the past tense. For example,

B: How was winning the lottery?
A: It was great.

B: Was climbing the highest mountain such a good idea?
A: It sounded cool at the time.

Here, "it" refers directly to what A did.

Answer (score 0):

> Person1: I won the lottery, it was great.(past for person 1)

> Person2: That is great.(present for person 2)

---

> Person1: I climbed the highest mountain last month.

> Person2:That sounds cool, **not** that sounded cool.