# A: She kissed me. B: That "was/is" awesome. - what are the differences?

Tags: meaning, tense

**Example 1**

> A: She kissed me.

> B: That **was** awesome.

When "was" is used.

It can be interpreted as "The fact that she kissed you was awesome."

**Example 2**

> A: She kissed me.

> B: That **is** awesome.

When "is" is used.

It can be interpreted as "The fact that she kissed you is awesome."

The past event can have a positive effect or consequence in the present.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: "That is awesome" is not talking about an effect or consequence in the present.  You could say "My breakfast yesterday at Mo's diner was delicious" and I could reply "That's great", meaning "I am glad you enjoyed it".  "That is awesome" in your context is simply an expression of a current opinion about something that has taken place. There is an implication that the past event has some *relevance* to the present.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [That is/was great. - which one should I use?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/315256/that-is-was-great-which-one-should-i-use) Also [What tense should I use here? What you painted is/was great!](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/143540/what-tense-should-i-use-here-what-you-painted-is-was-great)

Comment: @Tim thank you . But can it be the interpretation I say in my question "The fact that she kissed you is awesome"?

Comment: @vincentlin:  Yes it can.  **That** in "That is awesome" in your context refers to the content of your statement, to the assertion, not to a particular word or phrase.

Comment: When you use was: "She kissed me, that was awesome." Means: you felt awesome and the consequence  and effect of that was finish in the past.           When you use is: "She kissed me, that is awesome." Means: in the past you felt awesome and your feeling, effect and consequence of that are stell happening from past until now.